# Why are all the coefficients 0 in this LASSO quantile regression model?

Tags: r, lasso, quantile-regression

I am analyzing a simulated example from the `rqPen` R package where a quantile regression model with LASSO penalty is fitted:

```
library(rqPen)
n <- 1000
p <- 7
rho <- .5
beta <- c(3,1.5,0,2,0,0,0)
R <- matrix(0,p,p)
for(i in 1:p){
  for(j in 1:p){
    R[i,j] <- rho^abs(i-j)
  }
}
set.seed(1234)
x <- matrix(rnorm(n*p),n,p) %*% t(chol(R))
y <- x %*% beta + rnorm(n)

rq.lasso.fit(x,y,lambda=1,tau=0.5,intercept = FALSE)
```

As you can see, the last line produces :

```
 rq.lasso.fit(x,y,lambda=1,tau=0.5,intercept = FALSE)

Coefficients:
x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 x7 
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

which does not make sense since three predictors are different from zero in the simulation. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a general observation, I did not test it with your code (yet):
you fix lambda at 1. It might very well be that the lambda value is too large which automatically forces all coefficients to 0. Even if your simulated correlation between x and y is very strong, a sufficiently large lambda will force all coefficients to 0.
Try fixing lambda at various values between 0 and 1 and observe what happens with the coefficients. Start with very small values like 10^-10.

Comment: I think the value of lambda has something to do with this, but the problem is beyond this choice. I tried `rq(y~x, method="lasso",lambda = 1)` instead,  and tested several values of lambda, and this seems to work well. Thanks.